# Spacemacs - How to disable current parentheses highlight

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

This is probably simple.

But I've couldn't find a way to disable the current parentheses highlight on Spacemacs

[image: Spacemacs parentheses highlight]

At first, I thought this could be fixed by toggling the `(show-paren-mode)`, but it doesn't show any effect.

Comment: Looks like you are using some sort of [rainbow delimiters](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters). Find out just what you're using and look at its doc to take care of the problem. This is one of the problems with loading a giant, predefined sack of stuff. In principle, if the stuff in the sack is well done then it should be simple to discover what causes whatever you see. Here, you might use `C-u C-x =` to see what faces is used for that highlighting. The face name might help you track down the culprit code.

Answer (score 1):

In your config you can set `dotspacemacs-highlight-delimiters`, here is its documentation:

> dotspacemacs-highlight-delimiters is a variable defined in
>   ‘core-dotspacemacs.el’. Its value is ‘all’
>
> Documentation: Select a scope to highlight delimiters. Possible values
>   are ‘any’, ‘current’, ‘all’ or ‘nil’. Default is ‘all’ (highlight any
>   scope and emphasize the current one.

Answer (score 0):

My earlier and now deleted solution have stopped working. I found [Customize highlighting style](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47795/spacemacs-how-can-i-customize-the-highlight-style-of-a-matching-parenthesis) and with that knowledge I added

```
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
...
     dotspacemacs-excluded-packages '(smartparans)
...
)
```

and

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
...
    (custom-set-faces '(show-paren-match
      ((t (:foreground "gray24" :background "green")))))
...
)
```

You need to update this code with inherit or choose fitting colors for your theme.

I needed both solutions since if I just changed the style smartparans would take over. The challange with this problem is that the source is not unique.